# Single Table Inheritance in Rails and Devise options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-table-inheritance

If I have a main User model that has the standard devise line in it, and a Single Table Inheritance subclass model, how can I override my default devise options for the subclass? For example, the main user class has "confirmable", but I don't want that on the STI Subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrey said it is not possible.

As for the `confirmable` part. You can override your registrations controller for that model and after you build you subclass just call `skip_confirmation!` which [assigns a value](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L150) in the `confirmed_at?` column.

```
user = UserSub.new(user_sub_params)
user.skip_confirmation!
```

As for the other `devise` options, I am sure there is a way around. Edit your question to ask about more options if you need and I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible. Why? Because *confirmable* (for example) operates on the db level, involving column(s) like `confirmed_at?` and so on.

Since you have only one database table, you can not establish it in a way, that it contain a column for one submodel, and does not for another - it is one table.

And, after all, it does not hurt this much (if hurts at all) to care about it.